# Java EE Constructor Injection - How are fields set?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, inject

I'm still a bit confused with dependency injection using Java EE. I've tried looking through other SO posts but still don't have complete clarity. In my example below, the constructor for ClassA has the @Inject annotation above it, so those dependencies are injected into the constructor. But in the case of ClassB, that has it's own constructor which sets 2 fields. How do those fields get instantiated when it is injected into the constructor for ClassA? Or will ClassB's url and list fields be null when it is injected?

```
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB classB;
    private String str;
    private ClassC classC;

    @Inject
    public ClassA(ClassB classB, String str, ClassC classC) {
        this.classB = classB;
        this.str = str;
        this.classC = classC;
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    private String url;
    private List<Integer> list;

    public ClassB(String url, List<Integer> list) {
        this.url = url;
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd assume that this setup will fail because CDI isn't able to create an instance of ClassB. Note that the constructor of ClassA doesn't state it requires a _new_ instance of B but just some instance, e.g. if B was a singleton all instances of A would get the same instance of B injected. How that B instance is constructed depends on the rest of your code, e.g. you could have a producer method that returns it.

Comment: Is there any workaround? For testing purposes, I would prefer that ClassB's url gets set in the constructor so that I can point it to a test url. What if I made a second, no-argument constructor for ClassB? Would CDI be able to create an instance of ClassB that way?

Comment: You could provide a no-args constructor or you could create a producer method (annotated with `@Produces`) that creates your test instance.